# saving an array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, arrays

how is it possible to save an array in multiple locations ie. different view controllers in order to save the data in the arrays and allow it to be used afterwards by a table?
edit

objective c i have an ibaction with code

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[favoritesArray addObject: @"one"]; 
//and in the fav table view this code//
favoritesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
didContain = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if ([favoritesArray contains:@"one"]);

{ [didContain addObject:@"trial"]; }
```

however its crashing at the if part...

Comment: Could we get some context here?

Comment: i'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do.  what langauge?

Comment: objective c
i have an ibaction with code
   [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [favoritesArray addObject: @"one"];

and in the fav table view
this codefavoritesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    didContain = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if 
    ([favoritesArray contains:@"one"]);
    {
        
        [didContain addObject:@"trial"];
    }
however its crashing at the if part...

Comment: Could you please add the code in your comment to your question and format it as code?

Comment: Putting it in code font does not count as formatting it as code. I've gone and done that, and left a clue to one of your problems in the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
> [favoritesArray addObject: @"one"];
> ```

I assume you actually have the “`favoritesArray =`” in the original code, and simply missed it when copying. Otherwise, you're dropping the array on the floor and `favoritesArray` still holds `nil`.

> ```
> if ([favoritesArray contains:@"one"]);
>
> { [didContain addObject:@"trial"]; }
> ```
>
> however its crashing at the if part...

There are two problems with your `if` statement:

1. NSArray does not respond to `contains:`, which is what the crash is telling you. You need to send your array a message it does respond to, such as `containsObject:`, which is listed in the documentation.
2. As I indicated through the formatting I applied to your code, the `if` statement does not relate to the `{ [didContain addObject:@"trial"]; }` statement that follows it.

   That's because you put a semicolon after the `if` condition. An `if` statement does not take a semicolon between the condition and the statement; the statement must directly follow the condition (i.e. be immediately after the `)`). Moreover, a semicolon by itself is a valid, empty statement.

   So, you have an empty statement subject to the `if` (if the favorites array contains `@"one"`, do nothing), and you have the statement you meant to have controlled by the `if` standing on its own, unconditional.

   Cut out the semicolon after the `if` so that the `{ … }` binds to the `if` instead of being a separate statement.

Answer (score 1):

Alx, are you trying to access the data in `favouritesArray` from multiple objects? This is what I think you are trying to do, but without more context it is difficult to suggest a solution. Here is one possible approach:

Declare `favouritesArray` as a property in your controller class. (You could use `@property` and `@synthesize` to achieve this.)

Then, in your views, add your controller as an `IBOutlet` (called, say, `myController`). Then make connections in Interface Builder between your view and the controller. You will then be able to access the array from your view classes by writing:

`[[myController favouritesArray] objectAtIndex:3]`, for example.

In general, it is a bad idea to 'copy' data between different objects in your program. Unless there's a very good reason to do this, use references instead. Try to think about what object is the 'owner' for that array, and put it in that class.